# Paypal Transaction does not log on paypal account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am new for paypal payment process.
I have used 'paypal-sdk-merchant' gem for payment.

for sandbox account:

```
when I have completed payment via credit card then I am able to see my transaction in receiver account , but amount do no deduct from buyer account.
when I have paid via paypal account then I am able to see my transaction in receiver account as well as buyer account.
```

my code for payment via paypal account:

```
@set_express_checkout = @api.build_set_express_checkout({
  :SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails => {
    :ReturnURL => url_for(:action => 'success'),
    :CancelURL => url_for(:action => 'payment_methods'),
    :PaymentDetails => [{
      :OrderTotal => {
        :currencyID => "USD",
        :value => params[:payment][:amount] },
      :ItemTotal => {
        :currencyID => "USD",
        :value => params[:payment][:amount] },
      :ShippingTotal => {
        :currencyID => "USD",
        :value => "0.0" },
      :TaxTotal => {
        :currencyID => "USD",
        :value => "0" },
      :NotifyURL => "",
       :PaymentDetailsItem => [{
        :Name => params[:payment][:payment_for],
        :Quantity => 1,
        :Amount => {
          :currencyID => "USD",
          :value => params[:payment][:amount] } }],
          :PaymentAction => "Sale" }] } })

  # Make API call & get response
  @set_express_checkout_response = @api.set_express_checkout(@set_express_checkout)
  # Access Response
  if @set_express_checkout_response.success?
    @set_express_checkout_response.Token
    session[:payment_params] = params[:payment]
    redirect_to @api.express_checkout_url(@set_express_checkout_response) and return
  else
    @set_express_checkout_response.Errors
  end
```

If you did not get it, then I can elaborate more.
please help me, to get my transactions in paypal account.

Answer (score 0):

Your credit card transaction will not pull funds from the payer's paypal account because in your test payer is funding with the credit card, not the PayPal account. Your confirmation is ACK=Success and the funds appearing in the receiver account.